# Горячая кнопка

Tags: html, javascript

Хочу добавить на сайт горячую кнопку. При ее нажатии будет записано "привет" в поле. Как это сделать?

Comment: В какое именно поле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не совсем понятно про "горячую кнопку"...
если это клавиша на клавиатуре, то уже написали, если это кнопка на сайте, то где-то так:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('pole').innerHTML='Привет!';">Горячая кнопка</button>
```

на странице должен быть контейнер div или span с id="pole"

Answer (score 1):

event.keyCode - возвращает код нажатой клавиши, можно внедрить это в тег body:

```
<body onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 71) alert('Нажата клавиша G');">
```

Вместо alert и сделать функцию, которая будет добавлять "Привет" в нужное поле.